# ImageButton Border Transparancy - Removing the square border around round image is not working?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio

Hello Guys I need some help in creating Imagebutton. I created custom button on PS and then saved it in PNG format with transparent background. After that i patched my image with 9patch. Now i am using that image as a button in my layout but the image is showing colored background corners. I tried alot of things but its not removing.

[image: Here is my image]

Here is my XML

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/registerbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="123dp" />
```

[image: Here is the image of imagebutton It shows white corners]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the background attribute as `@null` like this :

```
android:background="@null"
```

If still you are getting that corner, it might be from the png file that you are using.

This is an example of what i get from `@null`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just checked the corners where from the output of 9patching.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the ouput of "9patching" operation added corners. Open the file and check if there are corners or not.
If that won' help, try switching `android:src` attribute with `android:background` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just checked the corners where from the output of 9patching

Answer (score 0):

And u can make .png button online using [this site](http://dabuttonfactory.com/#t=REGISTER&f=Calibri-Bold&ts=24&tc=fff&tshs=1&tshc=000&hp=20&vp=8&c=5&bgt=gradient&bgc=3cb371&ebgc=3cb371&shs=2&shc=444&sho=s)

Comment: Thanks it really helps.